# Why Roll-Up Summary enabled automatically some standard object?

Tags: master-detail

This article might be old one but I need to know clearly. Actually we can't be create MD relationship in standard objects only custom object am I rite? Roll-Up Summary support in only MD relationship. Why this enabled automatically some standard object.May I know what is the reason, could any one give me suggestion for this issue.

Comment: Master Detail and Roll-ups can be frustrating to understand and the topic is wide in scope. My advice is to refine your question if you want some traction on specific solutions unless you're just venting/trolling.

Answer (score 2):

Not all standard objects support MD relationships.

Examples where you may find limitations are:

1. Account > Case
2. Lead > any object

You can use the roll up helper app from the appexchange, declarative roll ups By Andy Fawcett or an example from Salesforceweek.ly blog using flow to create roll ups between non MD related objects.

http://www.salesforceweek.ly/2015/02/how-to-create-roll-up-summaries-using-flow-part-2.html